# Where to put standby control file in Physical standby database?

Tags: oracle-11g-r2, archive, standby

I am creating a physical standby database for which I am creating a standby control file using command = **ALTER DATABASE CREATE STANDBY CONTROLFILE AS '/oracle/dbs/stbycf.ctl';**

but It creates only one control file while I using 4 control files like:

**O:/cntrl_ims01/CNTRLIMS.ctl, O:/cntrl_ims02/CNTRLIMS.ctl, L:/cntrl_ims03/CNTRLIMS.ctl, L:/cntrl_ims04/CNTRLIMS.ctl**

, on standby host I am using same paths and structure as primary host, so where to place this single control file. ??

Answer (score 1):

You can copy the same standby file controfile to all the locations and use it.
All control_files have the same content.

If you are creating new standby, I would suggest to follow below method (which uses active duplication): https://dbaclass.com/article/how-to-create-physical-standby-database/

Comment: Please put all relevant content on this post so that when the article disappears some context of the answer remains available to future visitors.